# I don't Want YouTube bottom link in jQuery YouTube Popup Player Plugin

Tags: jquery, youtube, youtube-api

Hello I am embedding YouTube video in my website using jQuery YouTube Popup Player Plugin .
i don't want bottom link of YouTube with a logo . what should i do .pleas[image]e help .
thanks in advance.

Comment: Not possible. That logo there is *the* reason why they allow embedding it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you can do is add &modestbranding=1 to your string

example `http://www.youtube.com/embed/n3dBmbyoqbU?modestbranding=1`

Here you can find all the parameters availible
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters